# Problem when starting jupyterlab3.8 on mac

Tags: jupyter-lab, macos-catalina, macports

I have the following error while using jupyterlab on my macbook pro:

```
$ jupyter-lab-3.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 573, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 891, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (importlib-resources 0.0.0 (/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('importlib_resources>=1.4.0'), {'jsonschema'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/jupyter-lab-3.8", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('jupyterlab==3.0.13', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-lab')())
  File "/opt/local/bin/jupyter-lab-3.8", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .labapp import LabApp
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab/labapp.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab_server/app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.extension.application import ExtensionApp, ExtensionAppJinjaMixin
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.serverapp import ServerApp
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 75, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.services.contents.filemanager import AsyncFileContentsManager, FileContentsManager
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from send2trash import send2trash
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/send2trash/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .plat_osx import send2trash
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/send2trash/plat_osx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .plat_osx_pyobjc import send2trash
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/send2trash/plat_osx_pyobjc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Foundation import NSFileManager, NSURL
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._bridgesupport import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3279, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 575, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 588, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'importlib_resources>=1.4.0' distribution was not found and is required by jsonschema
```

FYI, I have installed it with macports and it worked:

```
sudo port install py38-jupyterlab
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but I get the same error.
I am wondering if there is a conflict with another install somewhere but I cannot fix the issue?

Any idea please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Edit (as an administrator) the file `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/importlib_resources-0.0.0-py3.8.egg-info/PKG-INFO` and replace, on line 3, `0.0.0` with the actual version of the port py38-importlib-resources (which is, as of this writing, `5.4.0`).

Follow https://trac.macports.org/ticket/64502 to see if/when a definitive solution of this issue is found.